# Magnetic field at the centre of a loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How is the magnetic field at the centre of a loop of current or a solenoid effected by different cross sectional area?

I understand B=unI gives the magnetic field, but it does not specify how it changes as the area of the coil changes.

Thanks.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/Biosav.html

Comment: The website "Grant Trebbin" is  where such an analysis is done for a loop using numerical methods. Embedded in that site is a link to an informative YouTube video.  http://www.grant-trebbin.com/2012/04/off-axis-magnetic-field-of-circular.html

Answer (score 2):

For a solenoid that is much longer than its diameter (if cylindrical), and for points inside the solenoid well away from the ends, the field is uniform all over the cross-section, and lengthways along the solenoid. The value of this field is $B=\mu _{0} \nu I$ in which $\nu$ is the number of turns per unit solenoid length, independently of the diameter or cross-sectional area. [The field becomes seriously non-uniform inside the solenoid within an axial distance of 2 *d* or so from the ends, *d* being the solenoid diameter.]

As implied by the formula $B=\mu _{0} \nu I,$ the flux density (field) inside the solenoid and well away from the ends is independent of the cross-sectional area of the solenoid, for a given $\nu$ and $I$, provided that the solenoid remains much longer than its diameter.

For a 'flat coil' things are quite different. The field is non-uniform over the cross-section even within the plane of the coil, and non uniform even along the  axis. At the centre of the coil (of *N* turns) the field is $B=\frac{\mu _{0}NI}{d}$ in which *d* is the coil diameter. So, for given values of $N$ and $I$, *B* is proportional to $\frac {1}{\sqrt A}$.